# How do I solve the zol sliding puzzle?

Tags: golden-sun-dark-dawn

On floor 4F in the Passaj Mountain Climb, there is a sliding puzzle. You have two large blocks of zol, and you need to slide each one into a slot on one side of the room. I have tried this over and over and over, and I keep getting stuck.

How do I solve this puzzle?

Comment: Assuming this is your first time there, you'll need the Cold Snap psynergy. Go about your merry way and come back later.

Comment: Ah. That would be why I am having issues. :)